# Jquery validator reset $.validator.setDefaults({ onfocusout: false, onkeyup: false }); in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

are there any way to reset **$.validator.setDefaults({ onfocusout: false, onkeyup: false });** in MVC3. I want to change the value in to some thing like 
**$.validator.setDefaults({ onfocusout: true, onkeyup: true });**
after I click a button.
How to archive this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setDefaults` should be set before `$('form').validate()` is called. Once `validate()` is called, the default are not used, so you must update the instance settings:

```
var settings = $('form').validate().settings;
settings.onkeyup = ...
```

(answer by bruce:[link answer](http://forums.asp.net/p/1840918/5136065.aspx/1?Re%20MVC3%20jquery%20validator%20How%20to%20reset%20validator%20setDefaults%20onfocusout%20false%20onkeyup%20false))