# How to make jQuery stop pre-validating my input dates?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4, which as I understand it uses jQuery validate for client-side validation.  Everything works pretty well and as expected, except for the HTML 5 date input

```
<input type="date" />
```

Whenever I begin typing a date into the input date field, the validator errors my field after the first number entered (assuming this happens onkeyup).  I found the questions that say to disable onkeyup validation using:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    onkeyup: false
});
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.

Is this a problem with the validate plugin, or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I explicitly stated that the answer in the question you cited did not solve my problem.  Thanks though

Comment: You should post your Javascript/HTML/MVC models so everyone can see exactly what's going on. [This might help](http://jqueryvalidation.org/date-method) in the meantime - the demo at the bottom illustrates that it *can* be done. On a side note, have you considered using a Datepicker?

Comment: Are you sure the message is coming from jQuery Validate?  If you've set `onkeyup: false` then the plugin is not doing it.  However, with ASP.NET, you also have the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin.  Also see:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/12293125/594235

Comment: Yeah I was just looking at that.  How do I make that not check validation onkeyup?

Comment: Validation is as per jQuery Validate and Unobtrusive Validation only facilitates a more automatic way to use it within ASP.NET.  In other words, you are already doing it correctly, but need to read the link I posted that explains what else you need to do.

Comment: If the duplicate question doesn't solve your problem, you obviously need to give more details on how your problem is different.