# jQuery Validator Submitting Forms With onsubmit = false and a Custom submitHandler

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

In my MVC project (which uses jQuery Unobtrusive Validation), I've got a view which contains multiple forms.  I'd like to prevent all forms from submitting when they are valid, and do something else instead.

Here is a brief snippet of one of the forms:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()
{
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
   // etc.
```

In my Javascript validation configuration, I've included `onsubmit: false`, `ignore: []`, and a custom `submitHandler`  - but my forms are submitting anyway.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: false,
    onsubmit: false,
    ignore: [],
    submitHandler: function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation;
        console.log("Form submission prevented.");
    }
});
```

I've also tried something like this unsuccessfully:

```
$('form').each(function () {
    $(this).validate({
        debug: false,
        onsubmit: false,
        ignore: [],
        submitHandler: function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation;
            console.log("Form submission prevented.");
        }
    })
});
```

Why are my forms still submitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"The idea is to prevent all forms from submitting when they are valid, and do something else instead."*

Then you simply need this...

```
submitHandler: function(form) { // <- argument is 'form' object only!
    // do something else, (or ajax)
    return false;
}
```

However, since you're using the MVC framework with `unobtrusive` validation, jQuery Validate's `.validate()` method is constructed and called automatically.

You must call `.setDefaults()` ***before*** your ASP framework calls `.validate()`.

Some people have success achieving this by putting `.setDefaults()` *outside* of their document ready function.

Also see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305576/594235

---

**Side-note**:

You also cannot put `.stopPropagation` (it's really `.stopPropagation()`; note the missing`()`) within just any type of function.

- `"event"` is **NOT** a valid argument provided by the developer for this callback function.  It's `"form"` and it only represents the form object.  You can change `"form"` into `"event"` or any other word, but it still represents the form object.
- [jQuery `.stopPropagation()` is for use within an event handler function (actions on an `event`), **NOT** for a plugin's callback function](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

Comment: Thank you for the very exhaustive answer!  Going back to `$.validator.setDefaults`, removing the `event.stopPropagation` bit, and moving the whole thing outside of `$(document).ready` did the trick.